# link software (ms access database) with sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I am using a software which is based in ms access database. And I want to link it to a sql server database.  I would like the connection to be live online.  Second by second, or as close to it as I can

What would be the best approach to linking the database so when I edit the access database in this other software it would populate my sql database online.

The software I am using will not recognize the database as usable if I make any major changes to the database.  So I have to take an outside in approach I think.  So I need to "monitor" the database for any changes (while its being edited) and then send the data to my online sql server.

Comment: Try linked servers option in sql server. You can specify ODBC source there

Comment: I have an application in MS Access that has linked tables to an online SQL Server database. It is live and works fine. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I am unable to find the documentation or a tutorial for something like this. (I have to approach this from the "server" because if the file structure is altered than my application won't recoginze it as a usable database.) If you could just explain what your process was or point towards a tutorial that would help me